# Why is incorrect endpoint being hit when using a view model, but works when explicitely specifying parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have two HTTP endpoints, defined as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<AdvertisementVM> GetAdsForRetailer(long userId, int page, int pageSize)
{
    //....
}
```

and

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<AdvertisementVM> GetAds(AdsViewModel vm)
{
    //....
}
```

where `AdsViewModel` is defined as

```
public class AdsViewModel
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public AppType AppType { get; set; }
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
}
```

with the following route configuration (behaviour is the same regardless of the order of these):

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "GetAds",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/GetAds/{appType}/{userId}/{page}/{pageSize}"
    );

routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "GetAdsForRetailer",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/GetAdsForRetailer/{userId}/{page}/{pageSize}"
    );
```

The problem I have is that the first endpoint, e.g. `GetAdsForRetailer` always gets hit, regardless of the URL I use, either

```
http://localhost/MyApp/api/AdsApi/GetAdsForRetailer/585290/0/3
```

or

```
http://localhost/MyApp/api/AdsApi/GetAds/customer/585290/0/3 // <-- note the extra customer parameter
```

However, if I don't use the `AdsViewModel`, and instead specify each parameter explicitly, as follows, the correct endpoint gets hit, e.g.

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<AdvertisementVM> GetAds(AppType appType, long userId, int page, int pageSize)
{
    // I get hit when params are declared, but not when AdsViewModel is used
}
```

I would expect that when I use the `/GetAds/customer` route, the `GetAds` endpoint would be hit, and the model binder would know how to bind the different route parameters to the object being passed in.

Why is this behaving differently to what I expect, and how can I get the model binder to bind to the viewmodel and pass that to the correct endpoint?

Comment: Have you tried putting defaults on your routes?

Comment: Can you check my answer?

Comment: I did. It's not the solution. I would have marked it as correct if it was.

Comment: Ah I see what I missed before. Although not an exact answer I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods with Complex types are exempted from selection algorithm - gist from here - http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection

"Complex types are an exception for a different reason. A complex type can only bind to the URI through a custom binding. But in that case, the framework cannot know in advance whether the parameter would bind to a particular URI. To find out, it would need to invoke the binding. The goal of the selection algorithm is to select an action from the static description, before invoking any bindings. Therefore, complex types are excluded from the matching algorithm."

I could get this working by using {action} attribute

In Register method

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "GetAds",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{userId}/{page}/{pageSize}"
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "GetAdsForRetailer",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{appType}/{userId}/{page}/{pageSize}"
);
```

In Controller

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("GetAds")]
public IEnumerable<SampleModel> GetAds(long userId, int page, int pageSize)
{
    //do something here
}

[HttpGet]
[ActionName("GetAdsForRetailer")]
public IEnumerable<SampleModel> GetAdsForRetailer([FromUri]SampleModel model)
{
    //do something here
}
```